# error with the limits library visual c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, machine-learning, header-files, libsvm

I've trying to compile `libSVM` on `W10` with `Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise compiler` and I get this error.
I type nmake -f makefile.win

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
cl.exe -nologo -O2 -EHsc -I. -D __WIN32__ -D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -c timer.cpp
```

> timer.cpp
>   timer.cpp(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'limits': No such file or directory
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
>   Stop.

It seems some problem with visual studio installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've think that was something related to the C++ Compiler.